# Jquery how to get specific css values from css properties with stacked value options such as font-family

Tags: jquery, css, properties, fonts, selector

Is there a way to get the first or any other specific value item from css property value stack in Jquery?

```
body {
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

.

```
var firstFontOption = $('body').css('font-family') //How can I store only "Calibri" referencing the above?

var secondFontOption = $('body').css('font-family') //How can I store only "Arial" referencing the above?
```

I only got `$('body').css('font-family')` showing all the values "Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif". Does Jquery has a first, second or other css value selector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is split the string like so:

```
 $('body').css('font-family').split(",");
```

That should give you an array of Strings:

```
 ["Calibri", "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif"]
```

You can then access this array by index so to get Calibri:

```
 $('body').css('font-family').split(",")[0];
```

And to get sans-serif:

```
 $('body').css('font-family').split(",")[3];
```

I don't know if there is a cleaner way, but this will work

Comment: You might also want to `$.trim()` each of the results to get rid of the extra whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

For getting a specific property you could simply point to that div/HTML tags and get the inline css property. Like this:

$('body').css('font-size');

```js
alert($('.text').css('color'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text" style="color:red">
  Alpha To Delta
</div>
```

');